# Form submit isset not working, when i click on the button it is always saying lol instead of saying working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have written this code for my website but it is not working
I have a small php code in which i want to check that the submit button is clicked or not please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>THUNDR</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="thundr_back">
            <div id="thundr_nav">
                <div id="thundr_head">!url shortner</div>
            </div>
            <div id="thundr_body">
                <div id="thundr_msg">
                    <div id="msg1">!url shortner</div>
                </div>
                <div id="thundr_bx">
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="text" id="thundr_link" name="thundr_link" value="" placeholder="enter your link here" required>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="shorten">
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                              echo "<script> alert('working'); </script>";
                            } else {
                              echo "<script> alert('lol'); </script>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        <div id="thundr_custom">need custom names for your url?</div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="thundr_ft"></div>
        </section>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working properly. You do not need `else lol` part as that will react on page load when submit is not made. remove that, press submit and you will get "working", Also i really hope you saved that page as `.php`; Also it si allways advised to set action attribute on form, if you are trying to submit on same page, just live it empty; `action=""`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use PHP code after `</form>`.
Please go through the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>THUNDR</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <section id="thundr_back">
                <div id="thundr_nav">
                    <div id="thundr_head">!url shortner</div>
                </div>
                <div id="thundr_body">
                    <div id="thundr_msg">
                        <div id="msg1">!url shortner</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="thundr_bx">
                        <form method="post" action="">
                            <input type="text" id="thundr_link" name="thundr_link" value="" placeholder="enter your link here" required>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="shorten">
                            <div id="thundr_custom">need custom names for your url?</div>
                        </form>
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                                echo "<script> alert('working'); </script>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<script> alert('lol'); </script>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="thundr_ft"></div>
            </section>
            <script src="main.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is not correct, it does not matter where it is. Page will reload on submit and catch submit event at beginning of PHP file if it wants to. Read my comment to OPS question...

Comment: @THUNDR What worked?!?! Everything si the same, it does not matter where the PHP code is! This answer is not correct nor relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `else`. Make sure the file where you wrote your code has
`.php` extension.  An example would be,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
<label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be submitted on the same page.</p>

</body>
</html>

<!-- You can put this anywhere, start -->
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  echo '<script>alert("Form Submission Success")</script>
 }
?>
<!-- You can put this anywhere, end -->
```